# How can I set a minimum passing score for a qualification test?

Tags: mechanicalturk

I want to create a qualification test using AMT's command-line interface. This test will only use question types that can be automatically scored by AMT. I can set the individual score for each question, but cannot find any documentation on how to set a minimum passing score for the test. For example, if a worker scores below 80, I would like them to fail the test. If they score above 80, I would like them to pass the test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Qualification test doesn't work like pass/fail. It assigns a QualificationScore. You can use QualificationValueMapping in the AnswerKey to translate a test score into a particular set of qualification scores (see: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSMechTurk/latest/AWSMturkAPI/ApiReference_AnswerKeyDataStructureArticle.html). The pass/fail element has to be part of your QualificationRequirement for a particular HIT - i.e., "pass" should mean a score higher than the QualificationRequirement's threshold and fail should be lower than that. Mapping would then allow you to translate total points into, e.g., values above and below the requirement's threshold.

Comment: Thank you! So just to be clear, there is no way to change the dialogue after an automatically graded test that says "Congratulations You have passed this qualification test with a score of X!"? They will always pass but sometimes with a score that is below my HITs threshold?

Comment: @willwest I guess if you get a score of zero it might say something else, but I don't think there's any way to modify the message.